# ArrayCollection is empty after ajax call

Tags: ajax, symfony

In my listing i do this for render my action

```
{{ render(controller("SNLikeBundle:Like:likeUser" ,{'id':obj.id })) }}
```

My action is

```
 /**
     * @Route("/bar/{id}", name="bar", options={"expose"=true})
     * @ParamConverter("my_obj", class="MYBundle:MyClass", options={"mapping": {"id": "id"}})
     */
    public function likeUserAction(MyClass $my_obj){

        $rows = $my_obj->getLike(); //array Collection Length 3

    ...more code...
```

my javascript is (i use https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle)

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: Routing.generate(url,{ // bar
            id:$(this).attr('id').split("-").pop(), //id of my obj
        }
    ),
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function() {
        //loading
    },
    success: function(msg) {
       //more code
    },
    error: function() {
       //more code
    },
    complete :function() {
       //more code
    }
})
```

With a button i do the same call but with ajax call, but arrayCollection length = 0

```
$rows = $my_obj->getLike();
```

my `$my_obj` is defined and correct

Comment: Can you show up your javascript code, the ajax call, please?

Comment: Is your first parameter of Routing.generate() `"SNLikeBundle:Like:likeUser"` ? because you wrote `url`. If it is, are you sure your object `$my_obj` is the same in both normal and ajax call?

Comment: are you create a new converter like Documentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#creating-a-converter

Comment: @ahmedhamdy Why i have to create a new converter? $my_obj is correct..For to be sure, i have also do a query, but the same results, arrayCollection is Empty

Comment: @maphe The object after ajax call is correct

Comment: I can't understand how `$my_obj` would be the same object, but without ajax, $like property is hydrated well, and with ajax it is not. There might be a missing information that we cannot help you without... Maybe some dumps of `$my_obj`...

Comment: @maphe in XDebug was empty, but in reality it is not empty ...